# How to Solve Button Alignment Issue?

Tags: wordpress, button

Recently I updated Ultimate Blocks plugin on one of my WordPress website and right after the update, all the buttons that I used aligned left automatically.

I want to align all buttons to center, but the problem is that I have to edit all posts manually which would take a lot of time. Is there any way to do it in once?

Problem screenshot:

[image]

Issue page: https://icemakercage.com/best-ice-makers/

Almost all the posts published before the update has the same issue. New ones are fine.

Comment: Would you add the code into the question please? We ask that all questions contain a [mcve].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The class of the container of your button is "align-button-left"

You can change this class to "align-button-center" and the modification will be effective on all of your button

In jQuery you can do this :

```
$('.ub-buttons').removeClass('align-button-left')
$('.ub-buttons').addClass('align-button-center')
```